# Jira custom fields - how to use jquery in velocity edit.vm

Tags: jquery, jira, velocity, custom-fields, jira-plugin

I am trying to write some relatively simple custom field.

This is an extract from my edit.vm:

```
$webResourceManager.requireResource("cz.firma.rozy:zakaznik")
<input id="test" style="width:500px"
       type="text" placeholder="Sem zadejte ID" value=""/>
<button id="buttonID" >Use ID</button>
```

And here is my simple zakaznik.js:

```
AJS.$( "#buttonID" ).click(function() {
    AJS.$("#test").hide();
});
```

Finally atlassian-plugin.xml

```
<web-resource key="zakaznik-resources" name="zakaznik Web Resources">
    <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
    <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:jquery</dependency>
    <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:jquery-ui-other</dependency>
    <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:aui-select2</dependency>
    <context>atl.general</context>
    <context>atl.admin</context>
    <resource type="download" name="zakaznik.css" location="/css/zakaznik.css"/>
    <resource type="download" name="zakaznik.js" location="/js/zakaznik.js"/>
    <resource type="download" name="images/" location="/images"/>
    <context>zakaznik</context>
  </web-resource>

...
  <customfield-type name="Pridani zakaznika" i18n-name-key="customer-add.name" key="customer-add" class="cz.firma.rozy.jira.customfields.CustomerCustomField">
    <description key="customer-add.description">Plugin, ktery prida zakaznika z abry</description>
    <resource name="view" type="velocity" location="templates/viewCustomer.vm"/>
    <resource name="edit" type="velocity" location="templates/edit.vm"/>
  </customfield-type>
```

Plugin is successfully built and installed in JIRA (v6.2.3) and I can add this field to any screen. When I click on this added button, I would like to see, that input is hidden.  When I click on my button, nothing is done and editing mode is closed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please split your problem up into separate questions.

Comment: Ok, I was splitted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change path in requireResource directive in Velocity template:

For example, if your pom.xml contains these strings:

```
<groupId>com.bla-bla.groupId-bla</groupId>
<artifactId>my-plugin-bla-bla</artifactId>
```

And web-resource with js file has key="zakaznik-resources" (according to your sample)

Then you must use this directive:

```
$webResourceManager.requireResource("com.bla-bla.groupId-bla.my-plugin-bla-bla:zakaznik-resources")
```

To self-control you can use Firebug or other browser plugin/tool to check availability of your js files on this page.

Comment: extract from pom.xml: 
`<groupId>cz.firma.rozy</groupId>
 <artifactId>zakaznik</artifactId>`

so my requireResource is:
`$webResourceManager.requireResource("cz.firma.rozy.zakaznik:zakaznik-resources")`
Is it OK? I am not sure if I need this require statement when I am using <context> in my atlassian-plugin.xml in web-resource??

But result is still the same. After I clicked on my button edit mode was closed. Firebug is quite and there are no errors or warnings

Comment: Check with your tool - is your js file is available from this page? If yes - put breakpoint to your method and check it behavior

Comment: I check my code and have one more advise: use onclick attribute in input tag: <input id="test" onClick="someMethod()" .../>. And move your hiding logic into appropriate method someMethod() { AJS.$("#test").hide(); } in js file

Comment: Ok, nearly it is done, thank you very much:-) Now, when I click my button, input is hidden and almost immediately is edit mode closed. (without my other interaction)

Comment: Ok, when I developed plugin for JIRA, I get significant help from this book: "JIRA 5.x Development Cookbook" by Jobin Kuruvilla

Comment: Ok, finally I have a solution of this problem. I must use:
`someMethod(event) { 
event.preventDefault();
AJS.$("#test").hide(); 
}
Thank you for your advices:)